# Why is lodash some not working here as I expect?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array

```
arr = ["jenny", "lucy", "jason"]
```

I do

```
_.some(arr, "jenny")
```

and it throws false

Comment: There is a case where a string is allowed in the place of the predicate.  But that is for object property names.  If there is an element in the list that has a property with that name and a truthy value, then `_.some` returns true.  For your case, you need to supply a function, as others have said, something like `_.some(arr, val => val == 'jenny')`

Comment: If you have an array of primitive types then you could use `_.includes` or the native array `includes` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case (an `array`) the predicate must be a function to check the values.

```js
var arr = ["jenny", "lucy", "jason"]
var result = _.some(arr, (x) => x === "jenny");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## Resource

- [`_.some(collection, [predicate=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs#some)

  > **Arguments**
  >
  > - `collection (Array|Object)`: The collection to iterate over.
  > - `[predicate=_.identity] (Function)`: The function invoked per iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `_.some` needs to have a function callback as its second parameter:

```
arr = ["jenny", "lucy", "jason"];
 _.some(arr, function(val) {return val === 'jenny'});
```